# ImportError and [wsgi:error] while trying to import a python3 file on a Flask/apache2 web server

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to run a Flask app with Python3/apache2 on Ubuntu16.04. But I run into an error if I try to make an import of file.py within the **init**.py of the FlaskApp.

My application structure: 
\var\www\FlaskApp:

> ```
>        |- FlaskApp\
>            |- templates\
>            |- static\
>            |- content_management.py
>            |- __init__.py
>        |- FlaskApp.wsgi
> ```

Here is the printed description of the error:

```
root@ordi:~# service apache2 restart
root@ordi:~# sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.463465 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7535:tid 139662857328384] [client ]     import content_management, referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.463497 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7535:tid 139662857328384] [client ] ImportError: No module named 'content_management', referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780434 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ] mod_wsgi (pid=7534): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module          ., referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780535 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ] mod_wsgi (pid=7534): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi'., referer:           http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780941 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780973 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780978 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780985 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>, referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboar          d/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.780988 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ]     import content_management, referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
[Thu Aug 09 13:59:58.781007 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 7534:tid 139662790186752] [client ] ImportError: No module named 'content_management', referer: http://www.MyWebSite.com/dashboard/
root@ordi:~#  mod_wsgi (pid=7534): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module
```

FlaskApp.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'SecretKey'
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
from content_management import content

TOPIC_DICT = Content()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route('/dashboard/')
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TOPIC_DICT = TOPIC_DICT)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I could reset the server and reinstall it in less than an hour, but I would rather like to understand the problem. 
Why my **init**.py file cannot import the content_management.py file?
How can I solve this problem? Should I write sys.path.insert() everywhere and pray?

Comment: The error log you posted tells you exactly what's wrong: `ImportError: No module named 'content_management'`  The mod_wsgi entrypoint has no knowledge of this "content_management" module.  Note that mod_wsgi is most likely not going to run your app from your project root.  You either need to package up "content_management" and expose it (i.e. install it) to whatever your mod_wsgi python runtime is (or in your apache config add the project root to your PYTHONPATH.)  You can also just do `sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp")` but that's brittle for lots of reasons.

Comment: Try a relative import of ``from .content_management import content``. The fact that ``__init__.py`` is being loaded indicates module search path has been set okay for your project.